# Find non overlapping area between two kde plots in python

Tags: python, feature-selection, seaborn

I was attempting to determine whether a feature is important or not base on its kde distribution for target variable. I am aware how to plot the kde plot and guess after looking at the plots, but is there a more formal doing this? Such as can we calculate the area of non overlapping area between two curves?

When I googled for the area between two curves there are many many links but none of them could solve my exact problem.

**NOTE:**
The main aim of this plot is to find whether the feature is important or not. So, please suggest me further if I am missing any hidden concepts here.

What I am trying to do is set some threshold such as 0.2, if the `non-overlapping area > 0.2`, then assert that the feature is important, otherwise not.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

x0 = df.loc[df['survived']==0,'fare']
x1 = df.loc[df['survived']==1,'fare']

sns.kdeplot(x0,shade=1)
sns.kdeplot(x1,shade=1)
```

## Output

[image]

## Similar links

- [Fill area of overlap between two normal distributions in seaborn matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53574569/9214357)
- [Python: Overlap between two functions (PDF of kde and normal)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29244352/9214357)
- [Fill area-between two curves in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57969088/9214357)

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to measure the similarity between two functions.

One option is to define the overlap between both functions as their dot-product:

```
# ensure both functions are normalized (self-overlap = 1)
x0 /= np.dot(x0, x0)
x1 /= np.dot(x1,x1)
overlap = np.dot(x0,x1)
```

Instead of multiplying the individual function values as above, you may calculate their difference and take, for example, the mean. This is similar to a loss function in machine learning:

```
d = np.absolute(x0 - x1)
mae = np.mean(d)    # mean absolute error
mse = np.mean(d**2) # mean square error
```

If the data is represented on different grid this approach won't work. But you can interpolate your functions and represent them on a new, common grid. A basic example is available in the [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-interpolation-interp1d). The interpolated data can then be used in the above code snippets.

Comment: It gives `ValueError: shapes (549,) and (342,) not aligned: 549 (dim 0) != 342 (dim 0)`

Comment: Well, the data needs to be represented on the same grid of course. If it is not, you can try  interpolation.

Comment: So, how to calculate the overlap given in the question?

Comment: I don't know your data and the relations of their grids, so I just linked to the SciPy documentation on 1D-interpolation.

Comment: that's ok,  I appreciate your effort.